# SQL Error: 1452, SQLState: 23000 using eclipse link

Tags: java, spring, eclipselink

I have mapped my entities

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user", schema = "swprojekt", catalog = "" , uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "user_id") })
public class UserEntity {
    private int userId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String password;
    private String email;
    private String addressHouseNumber;
    private String addressStreet;
    private String addressCity;
    private String addressState;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private int isAdmin;
    private List<DoctorspecializationEntity> specializations = new ArrayList<DoctorspecializationEntity>();

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name="join_doctor_specialization_to_user",
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="doctor_specialization_id", referencedColumnName="doctor_specialization_id"))

    public List<DoctorspecializationEntity> getSpecializations() {
        return specializations;
    }

    public void setSpecializations(List<DoctorspecializationEntity> specializations) {
        this.specializations = specializations;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false)

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
```

and doctor specialization

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "doctorspecialization", schema = "swprojekt", catalog = "")
public class DoctorspecializationEntity {
    private String name;
    private int doctorSpecializationId;
    private List<UserEntity> users;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="specializations")
    public List<UserEntity> getUsers() {
        return this.users;
    }

    public void setUsers(List<UserEntity> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "doctor_specialization_id", nullable = false)
    public int getDoctorSpecializationId() {
        return doctorSpecializationId;
    }

    public void setDoctorSpecializationId(int doctorSpecializationId) {
        this.doctorSpecializationId = doctorSpecializationId;
    }
```

They have m:n relation. In database additional  table is generated for holding their primary keys. I have trouble inserting data with foregin key.

Currently i am using

```
                userDAO.add(u); // Add user to database
                u.getSpecializations().add( docSpec ); // Add specialization to user
                userDAO.update( u ); // Update table in database thus inserting in m:n table foregin key of user and specialization.
```

add and update have implementation as following

```
@Transactional
public void add(UserEntity u) {
  em.persist(u);
}

   @Transactional
    public  void update( UserEntity u ){
        em.merge( u );
    }
```

However i am getting same result , and that is

SQL Error: 1452, SQLState: 23000, Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

When updating the table , primary key of instance of user already exists , so does primary key of specialization , so why does it keep complaining?

Is there a nice way to fix this?

Thanks for help

Comment: Turn on Logging for EclipseLink and show the SQL statement that is causing the issue: https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Logging  You might also check the join table constraints to see if it allows duplicates or not, and if the docSpec/user reference mght already exist.